# Out of Memory Exception running a large Insert script

Tags: sql, sql-server

> I need to execute a large Insert script of size 75MB in my database. I
>   am using the built in SQL command tool to run this script, but it
>   still throws the same error - "There is insufficient system memory in
>   resource pool 'internal' to run this query."

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d TestDB -i C:\TestData.sql
```

How to resolve this memory issue, when the last resort of running the script through **SQLCMD** does not work?

Note - Increasing the Maximum Server Memory(in the Server Properties) did not resolve this problem.

Comment: break it into pieces........

Comment: Is there any other way to make this script work, other than batching the entries? I don't want to manually batch this enormous query every time. I intend to run this Insert script very frequently.

Comment: what version of sql server are you on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query. on sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266663/there-is-insufficient-system-memory-in-resource-pool-default-to-run-this-query)

Comment: @ydoow -- I am on SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @ydoow - It is not a duplicate. Increasing the Maximum Server Memory(in the Server Properties) did not resolve this problem.

Comment: Have you considered using bcp instead of insert clauses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I face the same issue recently. What I have done is added Go statements for every 1000 inserts. This worked perfectly for me.

Go statement will divide the statements into separate batches. So every batch treated as separate Insertion. Hope this will help you in some way.

Comment: Earlier I tried with the GO statements and it did work for me.  
Is there any other way to make this script work, other than batching the entries? I don't want to manually batch this enormous query every time. I intend to run this Insert script very frequently. Also were you able to execute the modified query(With GO statements) through SSMS?

Comment: So did you manually insert all the GO statements for every 1000 statements? I have more than million insert statements, I dont want to do this manually. Also I intend to run this script very frequently.

Comment: No, I have not done insertion manually. SSMS itself executed it successfully. However putting `Go ` statement for a million of records is another pain.